# Ruby on Rails: Querying Serialize Data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

I have a controller. In this controller, i have this query:

```
def show
  @registration =  Registration.where("owner_id = ? OR send_to_id = ? OR cc_id = ?", current_user, current_user, [current_user].to_yaml)
end
```

It's working on `owner_id` and `send_to_id` buton `cc_id`, its not working.

Can you give me some tips on how to query a serialize data?

**UPDATE:**
I'm using MySQL.

Comment: You can use PostgreSQL [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html) for this purpose.

Comment: Is this working on MySQL?

Comment: @BartSabayton what does cc_id store and what's its class?

Comment: It's a serialized data. So, it stores an array. my sample data is this ->  ["4", "5"]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using postgreSql as your DB, have a look at this gem '**[activerecord-postgres-hstore](https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore)**' it will help you in querying your result as expected.